# MYSQL Get lowest value in column of a group specified by another column

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id  name  yearofstudy  mark

1   Alain A       2    75
2   Michael B     3    85
3   Chen C        1    55
4   Caroline D    2    60
5   Mohamed E     2    60
6   Alex F        1    55
7   Sofia O       3    78
8   Samir O       1    85
9   Rob G         2    78
10   Big K        3    55
```

And I'm trying to get the id, name, year and mark of the students with the lowest (and highest) mark in each year which would give:

```
id  name  yearofstudy  mark

3  Chen C       1      55
4  Caroline D   2      60
10  Big K       3      55
```

SQL isn't my strong point and I've been trying using the MIN() function but I haven't managed to get it right yet and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: Sorry, added it now

Comment: Both Alex and Chen have scored the least (55) for the records corresponding to `yearofstudy = 1` and same for Caroline and Mohamed for `yearofstudy = 2`. Any idea on how you want to pick one for these years then?

Comment: @DhruvSaxena I'd just pick the one that has a lower id (that should suffice for my needs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a subquery to get the `min()` and `max()` for each `yearofstudy`, and joining it to the original table. (You did say you wanted lowest and highest, right?)

```
select t.id, t.name, t.yearofstudy, t.mark
from t
  inner join (
  select 
      yearofstudy
    , min(mark) as minMark
    , max(mar) as maxMark 
  from t
  group by yearofstudy
  ) as m 
    on t.yearofstudy = m.yearofstudy
   and (t.mark = minMark or t.mark = maxMark)
```

or for just the lowest `mark` per year:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.yearofstudy, t.mark
from t
  inner join (
  select 
      yearofstudy
    , min(mark) as minMark
  from t
  group by yearofstudy
  ) as m 
    on t.yearofstudy = m.yearofstudy
   and t.mark = minMark
```

Comment: What does the "select t.* " do? I'm relatively new to SQL but surely as there is no column called 't' it would throw an error?

Comment: @c.timothy `t.*` means return all columns from the table/alias `t`

Comment: This is a big questions but how would I achieve the same result as this through using java with jdbc? The jdbc driver doesn't allow for alias'

Comment: @c.timothy You can specify the column names, I was just using `t.*` as shorthand to represent "_select the columns you want_". I have updated my answer to specify the column names.

Comment: Aaaah okay I understand it now, it represents the table that I'm selecting the columns from. Thank you for that it really helped make it click for me

Answer (score 0):

You could write the query as follows:

```
SELECT t1.* from your_table t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT yearofstudy, MIN(marks) as marks 
        FROM your_table GROUP BY yearofstudy
    ) t2
    ON t1.yearofstudy = t2.yearofstudy
    AND t1.marks = t2.marks
GROUP BY t1.yearofstudy
ORDER BY t1.yearofstudy, t1.id;
```

If all the `MIN` records for the `yearofstudy` are required, then you could simply remove `GROUP BY t1.yearofstudy`

[Demo](http://rextester.com/MORCG5924)